# I have a question about the monster's movement during the shooting game

Tags: c#

**What should I do when I want to give random moves to these enemies as they're coming down in a straight line?**

```
        enemyOne.Top += enemySpeed;
        enemyTwo.Top += enemySpeed;
        enemyThree.Top += enemySpeed;
        bossMonster.Top += enemySpeed;
        ambulance.Top += enemySpeed;
        addBullet.Top += enemySpeed;

        if (enemyOne.Top > 500)
        {
            enemyOne.Top = -650;
            enemyOne.Left = rnd.Next(20, 450);
        }

        if (enemyTwo.Top > 500)
        {
            enemyTwo.Top = -650;
            enemyTwo.Left = rnd.Next(20, 450);
        }

        if (enemyThree.Top > 500)
        {
            enemyThree.Top = -650;
            enemyThree.Left = rnd.Next(20, 450);
        }
```

I want to give the direction of the enemy in a fluid way, not a fixed value.

I'd appreciate your help.[image]

Comment: What you want is a noise algorithm, I recommend trying [Perlin Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise).

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it's an algorithm I already know.

Comment: There are lots of ways that you can implement Perlin Noise, you need to figure out which way provides the best result by trial and error, I believe it is the way to go. Highly recommend this [playlist by Coding Train](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qf4dIN99e2w&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bgPNQAdxQZpJuJCjeOr7VD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want the monster's movement to match your movement, you can set a tag and turn the appropriate switch case.**

```
     foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x is PictureBox && (string)x.Tag == "zombie")
                { 
                    if (x.Left > player.Left)
                    {
                        x.Left -= enemySpeed;
                        ((PictureBox)x).Image = Properties.Resources.bossM;
                    }
                    if (x.Left < player.Left)
                    {
                        x.Left += enemySpeed;
                        ((PictureBox)x).Image = Properties.Resources.bossM;
                }              
            }       
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a random way to come, not by the player's movement?

Comment: I don't know because I haven't seen your entire code, but if you made the code by frame, you can divide the area by frame and move it. Putting random variable regions in motion is not a difficult task.